# Could clicking a Grabify link to my Facebook page get me hacked?

Tags: malware, account-security, facebook

My newest boyfriend sent me a [Grabify](https://grabify.link/) link on Messenger. Without thinking (probably because of trusting him), I clicked the link (yeah, I'm an idiot, lol). The link has routed to my Facebook account.

I'v done some searches online but I find no answer. I just wanted to know if there's any possibility that he was able to get my Facebook/Messenger login information or if my account is hacked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phone Hacked. How serious is it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/125079/phone-hacked-how-serious-is-it)

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am the creator of Grabify

No you cannot have your Facebook account hacked by clicking on a Grabify link.

To view the information it logs, you can see that here: https://grabify.link/faq/features

To remove any of you logs from the website, you can do that here: https://grabify.link/removeme

Answer (score 0):

Sending a link to your profile page through Grabify is a bit odd, indeed. Potentially, clicking on such a link could get your account hacked if one of the two following is true:

- You did in fact not end up on Facebook, but on a phishing site mimicing Facebook, and you entered your password there.
- There is some sort of vulnerability on Facebook. Getting the victim to click a link is a common prerequisit for exploiting many web app vulnerabilities.

I can't comment on if the first one is true or not. The second one, though, is unlikely. Sure, there has been vulnerabilities in Facebook. But on a big site like that they get fixed quickly. The chanse that your boyfriend would be using an unkown Facebook exploit against you is pretty low.

What you can do, just in case, is to change your password and log out all current sessions.

By the way, I wouldn't call you an idiot for clicking on a link your boyfriend sent you... I would have done the same.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that there's no guarantee the boyfriend was the one to send the link. It could have been an account compromise. There's not enough information to be sure either way -- the boyfriend could actually just be sending weird links -- but if it _had_ been malicious, compromising the account of someone you trust is a great way to make you more likely to fall for it.